# непонятна логика range(python)

Tags: python, range

задача:
Дано 10 целых чисел. Вычислите их сумму. Напишите программу, использующую наименьшее число переменных.

решение, которое считается правильным:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    number = int(input())
    sum += number
print(sum)
```

я не понимаю, почему в скобках десять. Ведь вообще range(10)- это от нуля до девяти. То есть программа должна была вывести сумму чисел от нуля до девяти Почему в данном случае это отображает именно число вводимых чисел? И зачем вообще указывать это число? Если у нас по условию всегда даются 10 чисел, которые надо просуммировать? Я еще понимаю, если бы в условии было сказано просуммировать первые 10 чисел из всех последовательностей, которые могут быть разной длины&

и почему нельзя сделать что-то вроде `for i in range(input())`? 
ведь в предлагаемом решение этот же инпут присваивается переменной n, то есть ту самую последовательность 
заранее спасибо:)

Comment: `input()` возвращает строку, а `range(строка)` — бессмысленное выражение, которое выдаст ошибку

Comment: «программа должна была вывести сумму чисел от нуля до девяти» — нет, не должна, потому что переменная `i` никак не используется. Можно даже написать `for wtf in range(3000, 3090, 9)` — получится точно такая же программа, потому что переменную `wtf` тоже никто не будет использовать

Comment: почему тогда если написать 
for i in range(4):
    print(i)
он выведет 0, 1,2,3
а если что-то вроде
sum=0
n=int(input())
for i in range (n):
print sum+=i
то не сработает ? 
переменная i используется, суммируется с sum

Comment: @КсенияЗорина Написать можно что угодно, бумага все стерпит. Но какое это будет иметь отношение к Вашей задаче?

Comment: @КсенияЗорина ну так просто не надо использовать переменную `i`. И да, вы в комментарии понаписали синтаксически некорректный бред, который просто не запустится

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    sum += int(input())
print(sum)
```

---

`for i in range(10):` - это просто цикл из десяти итераций

Answer (score 0):

Решение с наименьшим количеством переменных (исключая вариант с 10-ти кратным суммированием `int(input())` в коде), в данном случае, будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
print(sum(map(int, (input() for _ in range(10)))))
```

Если обратиться к коду из вопроса то:

```
sum = 0  # Объявляем переменную в которой будет аккумулироваться сумма
         # кстати sum это имя функции, 
         # а посему это имя использовать в 
         # качестве имени переменной не очень правильно
for i in range(10): # Создается цикл из 10 итераций.
                    # Впринципе в каждой итерации цикла можно использовать
                    # объявленную переменную i 
                    # (она будет принимать значения от 0 до 9) но,
                    # поскольку она нам не нужна,
                    # то хорошей практикой, для таких случаев,
                    # считается использование переменной _ 
    number = int(input()) # В каждой итерации для переменной number принимается
                          # вводимое пользователем значение 
    sum += number         # К переменной в которой содержится сумма значений
                          # прибавляем текущее значение
print(sum) # Выводим значение переменной sum
```

> Что-же касается Вашего предположения, что цикл должен вывести сумму значений `i`, то это произойдет в том случае, если вместо `int(input())`, в цикле вы будете использовать `i`.